# Изменения свойств одного элемента при активации другого

Tags: html, css, focus

Суть вот в чем, при клике на одну из иконок, должен высчечиваться соответствующий текст. Подумал реализовать это через `display:none;`на `div` с текстами,либо через `scale`, другого способа не знаю. Вот и получается что при `:focus` текст не появляется хоть сама функция работает. Подозреваю ошибку в синтаксисе, подскажите где не прав?

HTML

```
<div class="serviceIcon">
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
        <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
        <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="serviceContent">
    <div id="diagrammText">
        <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="techText">
        <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loopeText">
        <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="circleText">
        <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.serviceIcon #tech:focus + #techText{
transform: scale(1);
}
.serviceContent #techText{
transform: scale(0);    
}
```

Comment: С таким расположением элементов - никак. Могу показать через juqery или поменять расположение, что бы работало

Comment: да, можно поменять как было бы лучше?

Comment: Смотрите, я добавил 3 варианта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите открывать при `focus`, то нужно разместить элементы в один блок, что бы они были рядом:

```css
.serviceContent .icons:focus + div {
  display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent #diagrammText, 
.serviceContent #techText,
.serviceContent #loopeText,
.serviceContent #circleText {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="serviceContent">
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
    </div>
    <div id="diagrammText">
        <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
        <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
    </div>
    <div id="techText">
        <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
        <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
    </div>
    <div id="loopeText">
        <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
    </div>
    <div id="circleText">
        <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите использовать такое же расположение элементов, то придётся использовать скрипт:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.serviceIcon .icons').focus(function() {
    $('.serviceContent #'+$(this).attr('id')+'Text').css({'display': 'block'});
  });
  $('.serviceIcon .icons').blur(function() {
    $('.serviceContent #'+$(this).attr('id')+'Text').css({'display': 'none'});
  });
});
```

```css
.serviceContent #diagrammText, 
.serviceContent #techText,
.serviceContent #loopeText,
.serviceContent #circleText {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="serviceIcon">
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
        <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
        <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="serviceContent">
    <div id="diagrammText">
        <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="techText">
        <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loopeText">
        <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="circleText">
        <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

А если вы хотите использовать, что бы текст появлялся после всех элементов, но без скрипта, то нужно все иконки разместить в начале блока и с помощью `~` прописывать каждое id:

```css
.serviceContent .icons#diagramm:focus ~ #diagrammText {
  display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent .icons#tech:focus ~ #techText {
  display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent .icons#loope:focus ~ #loopeText {
  display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent .icons#circle:focus ~ #circleText {
  display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent #diagrammText, 
.serviceContent #techText,
.serviceContent #loopeText,
.serviceContent #circleText {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="serviceContent">
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
        <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
        <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
        <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
    </div>
    <div id="diagrammText">
        <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="techText">
        <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loopeText">
        <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="circleText">
        <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
        <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотрю скрипт в этом плане и правда выручает, ну мне надо по типу как в 3-ем варианте, только справа, для меня это по центру ибо после текста ещё будет картинка :)  P.S. JS только-только начал учить.

Comment: @adckiykpolb, не понял, что значит справа?

Comment: Тоесть вот так) текст справа от иконок< http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/7_1_2017/10/uPEIRSaiBEaHmXmyOujlQ.jpg >

Comment: @adckiykpolb, тогда вам подходит **третий** и второй  вариант