# Проблема с непонятным отступом у элемента

Tags: html, css, отступы

Непонятно почему у элемента справа образовался `margin` и не позволяет встать тексту на свое место (по идее).

```css
.icons  {
  display: block;
  width: 104px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(20, 20, 21, 0.14);
} 

.serviceContent{ 
  width: 35%;
  height: 50%;
  display: none;
  float: right; 
}

.serviceImage{ 
  width: 35%; 
  float: right;
  right: 0px;
  top: 20px;
}

.miniMenu{
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniMenu">
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
    <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
    <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
    <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
    <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
  </div>   
  <div class="serviceContent" id="diagrammText">
    <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
    <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="techText">
    <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
    <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="loopeText">
    <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
    <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="circleText">
    <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
    <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="serviceImage">
  <img src="img\apple-watch-mockup.png" alt="">
</div>
```

[image: trouble]

Comment: А Вы css сбивали для нормализации?

Comment: А вы можете 1. Сделать ваш код запускаемым? Картинки вы также можете добавить через загрузку изображений. 2. Пояснить с каким именно элементом (через селектор или более понятное описание проблемы)?

Comment: Да, клификс делал.Насчет какого элемента - с классом .icons

Comment: Отредактировал ваш код, чтобы код можно было запустить. Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: да, можно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блоки с классом `.icons` лежат внутри плавающего блока, которому назначены `65%` ширины. Поэтому справа от них остаётся много свободного места.

Сами `.icons` – обычные, неплавающие блоки, и поэтому занимают всю доступную им ширину.

Блоки с классом `.serviceContent` – снова плавающие, но `.icons` оттесняют их вниз.

UPD. Если текстовые блоки показываете и прячете скриптом, то попробуйте поставить все блоки `.serviceContent` перед всеми `.icons`.

UPD 2. Чтобы [обойтись стилями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611679/), назначьте текстовым блоками `position: absolute;`. Например, так: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/bgVbGb

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.icons {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 92px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 104px;
} 
.icons img {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 42px;
  border-top-left-radius: 42px;
}

.serviceContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 124px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

.serviceImage { 
  width: 35%; 
  float: right;
}
.serviceImage img { 
  height: auto;
  width: 100%; 
}

.miniMenu {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
}

#diagramm:focus ~ #diagrammText,
#tech:focus ~ #techText,
#loope:focus ~ #loopeText,
#circle:focus ~ #circleText {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniMenu">
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
    <img src="//placehold.it/104x92/c69/fff?text=1" alt="diagramm">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="1" class="icons" id="tech">
    <img src="//placehold.it/104x92/69c/fff?text=2" alt="tech">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="2" class="icons" id="loope">
    <img src="//placehold.it/104x92/9c6/fff?text=3" alt="loope">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="3" class="icons" id="circle">
    <img src="//placehold.it/104x92/f93/fff?text=4" alt="circle">
  </div>
  
  <div class="serviceContent" id="diagrammText">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="techText">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="loopeText">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="circleText">
    <h2>4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="serviceImage">
  <img src="//placehold.it/480x640/999/fff?text=Service%20Image" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: ага, я понял где недоглядел. беда в том что если им присваиваю флоат то они выстраиваются по горизонтали, не то что надо)

Comment: А если их вытащить в отдельную колонку? Получится три плавающих колонки: в левой останутся картинки-переключатели, в средней будут появляться описания к ним, в правой - картинка товара.

Comment: Или ещё проще - попробуйте поставить все блоки `.serviceContent` перед всеми `.icons`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Поменял местами, но текст как-то скрылся, а вынести в отдельную не вариант(http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611679/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Comment: Посмотрите новый вариант. Обновил ответ.

Comment: То что надо, у самого стали закрадываться мысли что без 'position:absolute' никак:) Спасибо